# How to query data in a XML file usin javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a sample XML file as follows:

```
  <audit>
     <asset>
         <user_Id>1</user_Id>
         <username>admin</username>
         <asset_id>1001</asset_id>
         <vin_7>2217841</vin_7>
         <make>xyz</make>
         <model>x5</model>
         <color>red</color>
         <reg_no>1234</reg_no>
         <note>null</note>
         <geopoint>
             <geo_lat>-6.23</geo_lat>
             <geo_long>50.43</geo_long>
         </geopoint>
         <status>incomplete</status>
     </asset>
     <asset>
         <user_Id>1</user_Id>
         <username>admin</username>
         <asset_id>1001</asset_id>
         <vin_7>2227841</vin_7>
         <make>abc</make>
         <model>x4</model>
         <color>blue</color>
         <reg_no>unknown</reg_no>
         <note>null</note>
         <location>test street</location>
         <geopoint>
             <geo_lat>-6.33</geo_lat>
             <geo_long>50.22</geo_long>
         </geopoint>
         <status>incomplete</status>
     </asset>
 </audit>
```

I want to get a list of 'vin_7' elements where username='admin'. How could this be done using JavaScript?

Comment: one asset tag can have multiple username and vin_7 tags? or is the sample wrong? How can we find which vin_7 element belongs to which username?

Comment: Yes I think you're missing open/closed asset tags

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes I have edited the sample. Sorry, never worked with XML before will appreciate any help.

Comment: @Harry The sample was faulty... Number of asset are assigned different username and vin_7 values.... I want to get a list of vin_7 having a particular username for instance 'admin'... what would be the best way to achieve this through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to load the XML file and select only the contents of the `<vin_7>` element whose `username` is `admin`. This uses XPath as mentioned by samuelgrigolato in his answer.

**Note:** I have used `document.write` lines only as a sample. It is not a good practice to use them. So, avoid them in your actual code.

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

xml = loadXMLDoc("asset.xml"); //Your input file name
path = " /audit/asset/vin_7[../username/text() = \"admin\"]"; //The XPath Condition
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var nodes = xml.selectNodes(path);
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        document.write(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
    var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var result = nodes.iterateNext();
    while (result) {
        document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("<br>");
        result = nodes.iterateNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp) might solve your problem. Just be cautious when dealing with old IE versions, the API has some differences.

XPath expression for your scenario: /root/asset/vin_7[../username/text() = "admin"]

EDIT: reading the question recent comments, this answer only applies IF every record has inside it's own asset tag, and a new "root" tag is created. I've update the xpath considering this.

Answer (score 1):

You might forgot to close asset tag. If you close your asset tag after first incomplete and from beginning and end of your XML, if you will provide one parent tag say for example < xml >< /xml >, then you can solve your problem with the following.

```
$(test).find("asset").each(function() {
    if($(this).find('username').text() == 'admin') {
        alert($(this).find("vin_7").text())
    }
});
```

Note: Here test is the variable where I have assigned the whole XML string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file shown above is stored on the server in file "audit.xml" the following code loads file from the server (there're other ways to load XML from string etc.) parses it and displays selected data:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
else  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.open("GET","audit.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

xNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/audits/asset[username='admin']/vin_7")

for (i = 0; i < xNodes.length; i++) {
    alert(xNodes[i].text)
}
```

This code works in IE, whose XmlDocument supports "selectedNodes" method. For other browsers you may need to add implementation of the method, e.g. http://richardpianka.com/2011/01/cross-browser-xpath/